# python selenium get current url of new tap (window_handles[0])

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the url of the `tap` active without switching to the `window_handles[x]`

I try to add `driver.current_url(driver.window_handles[0])`, but it does not work

```
driver.get("https://google.fr");
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    l = len(driver.window_handles)
    for x in range(0, l):
        #driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        print driver.current_url(driver.window_handles[0])
```

**Example:**

If I open new `tap` with new `url` `bing.com` the `driver.current_url` will show just `google` not the new `tap` url `bing.com`. And I don't want to switch to the new `tap` to get `url`.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. You should switch to each new tab/window to get its URL. Also note that `current_url` is a property - you cannot pass any arguments to it

Answer (score 1):

When you open a new tab in a browser with some URL, you need to get it registered so that selenium can access it. You need to switch to that tab using the `driver.window_handles` so that the tab gets registered, then only you would be able to access the URL of the tab using `driver.current_url`. I'm not if there is any other way to do this by using just selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.window_handles`to see all the url and you can use `driver.current_window_handle`to see current url. So, after you open new `tap`, you can see `driver.current_window_handle`then compare to `driver.window_handles`, then you can `switch_to.window` the correct url

Comment: How to get url from "current_window_handle" i try but i faild .

Comment: print(driver.current_window_handle)

Comment: yes i try it but it show the handle id "CDwindow-70888C4DFD051D13E3CAAAC9C561F663" not the url

Comment: you can print all the handles use driver.window_handles and see the same id ,and use driver.window_handle[i]to visit

Comment: the another solution is to use driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)

Comment: yes like u see in my code i was able to get all the "driver.window_handles" , and switch to it to get the url , but i dont wanna to switch

Comment: @Selenium , both `window_handles` and `current_window_handle` have nothing to do with **URLs**

Comment: i know,but i think he just want to switch to another window by handle

Comment: @Selenium , No. OP said *"And I don't want to switch..."*

Comment: but in the question ,he said 'don't want to switch to the new tap to get url.'